# column average with respect to other column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, average

I know someone might have read this question in past but again reposting it because earlier one was not very clear.

I have data frame with 4 variables ( Id, ASP,RSP,Volume), what i want is to take average of volume if the absolute difference between consecutive values of ASP and RSP is between +-0.03.

for ex.: in ASP and RSP 1st two observation have diffrence below 0.03 so for this take average of 5109 and 5707, now take next observation ( i.e 3rd cause 1st and 2nd already used) ASP=6.39 RSP=6.28 now though 4th observation have diffrence below 0.03,we can not club volume because it is under different Id 2202 so keep it same and so on..

Data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Id = c(2201, 2201, 2201, 2202,2202), 
                      ASP= c(6.29, 6.31, 6.39, 6.39,6.36),
                      RSP= c(6.29,6.28,6.28,6.36,6.36),
                      Vol= c(5109, 5707, 5999, 5853,6590))
```

Code:( i don't know how to take avg of volume if condition fails so taken 1 and zero :( )

```
n=dim(s)[1]

diff_asp_max=s$ASP[1]+0.03
diff_RSP_max=s$RSP[1]+0.03

diff_asp_min=s$ASP[1]-0.03
diff_RSP_min=s$RSP[1]-0.03


for ( i in 1:n)
{

  if (s$ASP[i]< diff_asp_max & s$ASP[i]>diff_asp_min & s$RSP[i]>diff_RSP_min & s$RSP[i]< diff_RSP_max & s$diff_StoreId[i]!=1)
  {
    s$a[i]<- 1
  }
  else
  {


    s$a[i]=0
    diff_asp_max=s$ASP[i]+0.03
    diff_RSP_max=s$RSP[i]+0.03
    diff_asp_min=s$ASP[i]-0.03
    diff_RSP_min=s$RSP[i]-0.03
  }
}
```

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: output <- data.frame(Id = c(2201, 2201, 2202,2202), 
                  ASP= c(6.29, 6.39, 6.39,6.36),
                  RSP= c(6.29,6.28,6.36,6.36),
                  Vol= c(5408, 5999, 5853,6590))

Comment: Maybe `library(dplyr); df1 %>% group_by(Id) %>% mutate(cid=cumsum(!(abs(c(0, diff(ASP)))<.03 & abs(c(0, diff(RSP)))<.03))) %>% group_by(cid, add=T) %>% mutate(Vol=mean(Vol)) %>% distinct %>% ungroup() %>% select(-cid)`? The last one is collapsed because the difference is within your given boundaries. (I don't know why it's kepts in your output example)

Comment: why is group 2202 not averaged? Their difference is within `abs(0.03)`

Comment: Hey LukeA, yes you are correct last entries should be clubbed. and its super thumps up!!! command worked for me..THANKS ALOT..

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way, it is not quit your output because row 2 is still in there, and it seems to me that group 2202 actually satisfies your criteria for mean.

```
ls1 <- split(df1,df1$Id)
ls2 <- lapply(ls1,function(x) {
  x$ASP_diff <- c(0,abs(diff(x$ASP)))
  x$RSP_diff <- c(0,abs(diff(x$RSP)))
  x$MeanVol <- ifelse(x$ASP_diff < 0.03 & x$ASP_diff < 0.03,mean(x[x$ASP_diff < 0.03 & x$ASP_diff < 0.03,"Vol"]),x$Vol)
  return(x[,c(1:4,7)])})
unsplit(ls2,df1$Id)
```